# A Method that can write to two Public datatables

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm Not really sure how to phrase this question, but i will try to explain what i'm trying to do.

Please Consider the following pseudo code:

```
public DataTable _Table1 = new DataTable();
public DataTable _Table2 = new DataTable();

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (true)
    {
        readFile(someFile,_Table1)
    }
    else
    {
        readFile(someFile,_Table2)
    }
}

public void readFile(string FileName,something* datatabletoWriteTo)
{
    datatabletoWriteTo.Rows.Add(add Stuff to The Data Table);
}
```

As you can see, I have 2 Public Datatables setup, i have created a method that can select the correct datatable to write information to. while reading a file, but i don't know what variable type to select to indicate to the program what datatable i want to write to (see the "something* type")I'm pretty new to programing so i don't know if it is even possible or what to google for.

Comment: Whats wrong with just `DataTable datatabletoWriteTo`?

Comment: Are the two datatables identical?

Comment: Yes They are identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use the type of your variable, in this case `DataTable`.

```
public void readFile(string FileName, DataTable datatabletoWriteTo)
{
    // parse file contents
    datatabletoWriteTo.Rows.Add(...);
}
```